# Android Studio build Cocoonjs by Gradle not ANT

Tags: android-studio

My project is dependency on Module A & B

And Module A is dependent on Module B

After I setup the dependencies,  Multiple dex exception is encountered.

> FYI
>
> My project is doing native + Cordova WebView
>
> and I try to accelerate by Ludei WebView+  for the low end model
>
> https://github.com/ludei/webview-plus

My project dependent on Cordova module & Ludei WebView+ module

Cordova module dependent on Ludei WebView+ module

After these setting I can successfully build by grade with no warning, but I do not pass dexDebug when I want to build application.
I got this error

> com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Lcom/ludei/chromium/BuildConfig;

I know it is officially recommended to build on ANT, I have did some trick I change the webview+ package name I can build the "debug" application but not in "release".

How can I set it properly in android studio to build it by gradle without having multiple dex exception?

---------UPDATE -------------

@Scott Barta Yes, here is whole cordova project under [project]/platforms/android.

The Whole project files. module: CordovaLib,webviewplus

> https://github.com/gaplo917/cordova-cocoonjs-gradle

I can build a debug with cocoonjs by changing the package name to another name,i.e. package="com.ludei.android.chromium" but with no luck on building a release version.

> https://github.com/gaplo917/cordova-cocoonjs-gradle/blob/master/webviewplus/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml

- if cocoonjs is not run properly, the application can still be built but when you request a cordova web view , it will crash!

Comment: Can we see all your build files, please?

Comment: @ScottBarta I create and uploaded the test project. Please kindly take a look!